# Delete a pointer as first key of std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, stl, stdmap

I was wondering how to properly delete a pointer which is the first key of a `std::map`. I can only figure this out for the second key. The first key is only readable.

Example:

```
std::map<char*,foo> myMap;
char* str = new char[3];
foo bar;
str[0]='h';
str[1]='i';
str[2]='\0';
myMap[str] = bar

/* some code */
for(auto element: myMap)
{
    delete [] element.first;
}
```

This doesn't seem to free the pointer. Did `std::map` lose the pointer somewhere? 
I am working on big data, so I need string structures as light as possible. That's why I worked with `char*` and not `std::string` (with a comparator functor given to the map).

**EDIT**

For more precisions:

- I am reading ADN sequences. For each pattern I am reading, i put its position in the map.(std::map>)
- I am using char* because std::string allocate more than required number of char
- My priority is not time of computing but space in memory.

I hope this help you to understand my question.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't prematurely optimizing?  How do you know that once you've put all the work that you need into working with char* that you won't be back at the overhead of string?

Comment: Why do you say `it does not seem to work`. In what way does it not work

Comment: Just use a `std::map<std::string, foo>`.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't free the pointer?

Comment: "This doesn't seems to free the pointer." - why do you say that? It deletes the array, leaving a dangling pointer in the map. I dread to think why you think this might be a good idea; just use `std::string`. Or `unique_ptr<char[]>`, if you really think you need the lightest possible type to manage a dynamic array.

Comment: Why do you delete the keys out of a working map?

Comment: What you call the "first key" is the key. What you call the "second key" is the value that corresponds to the key.

Comment: I say _it doesn't seems to work_ because valgrind said that there is leaks (definitly & undirectly). Using std::string, there no memory leaks... 

@molbdnilo, I said first key because I asked this to my coworkers, and they didn't understand it. They were always thinking about std::map<foo,ptr*>...

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You've not removed the first item from the map and your key on the first element is now a dangling pointer. The fact you can read the character array is down to chance.

Comment: @Arunas / Component: I think we can assume the deletions are only done when the map is about to go out of scope, so dangling pointers aren't an issue, but it would be nice if the question made that more explicit.

Comment: If valgrind says there are leaks, it should also provide some clues about their source. Does valgrind point you towards the allocations you store in the map? (BTW: if you erase an entry from the map, you must take care to free the key in that case too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resolved

Thank you all, loads of your comments help to solve my problem. I succeed in using std::string. I know, i told you that it was too weight. But I found the méthod *reserve(size_t n=0)* which allow exactly the place we want to. Now, there is no leak anymore.

Thanks again for your answers!

Sources:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/

Answer (score 1):

Your code already works (but isn't exception safe - a smart pointer would be).  Note that when memory is `delete`d, the program doesn't normally waste time changing it, it just changes some free/in-use records so a future allocation can consider that memory for reuse, so if you try to dereference the `delete`d pointers you have undefined behaviour but it might seem to still have the old contents - at least for a while.  I assume that's why you think the deallocation isn't working....

Comment: I am aware of this. I said that _it doesn't seems to work_ because of valgrind:
`1,520 bytes in 304 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 7
==7859==    at 0x40278F4: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:343)
==7859==    by 0x804CB45: getMerFromSeq(...`

Comment: @Atouk and what's in `getMerFromSeq`?  As a sanity check you could change to `std::string` temporarily and see if the leak is still reported.... (Ahhh... I see from another comment you've tried that - good).  Have you checked the delete[] calls are happening?  You're not sometimes `erase`-ing some keys without `delete`-ing their data beforehand?

Comment: In this function, i fill my char* with wanted characters, and do: myMap[myCharPtr] = something. Then, in another function I treat my data, then i call freeMyMap(MyMap) that did a loop, then did delete[] element->first. The same as my first post. And with std::string, there is no memory leaks. I'm trying with unique-ptr as said Mike Seymour. I will tell you if it works.

Comment: I just saw that you edit your comment. There is no delete at another part of my code.

Comment: @Atouk I'm afraid there's just too much up in the air to help you much more - you should try to get a 20-30 line complete program that illustrated enough of what you're doing to produce the valgrind leak report, then append that to your question so we have something concrete to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your map has two elements and you need to delete the first: `it->first` is a `char*` and `it->second` is a `foo`. Try the following code:

```
for(std::map<char*, foo>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); it++)
{
     delete[] it->first;
     myMap.erase(it);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if looks like he's using c++11, so his loop is fine and he doesn't need all the hideous iterators.  Calling erase isn't a bad idea, but shouldn't be necessary as the map should empty itself on destruction.  In fact, calling myMap.clear(); after the loop would probably be faster.

Comment: @Arunas: I agree with you! Indeed, I am thinking some other way of achieving what he asks without using char* especially after seeing his edit to the question.